# ZF2 where expression

Tags: php, select, model, zend-framework2, where-clause

In mu ZF2 project I have Model using TableGateway.
Inside function responsible for fetching objects based on search criteria (city, postal_code, range, type).

Generally I fetch rows of data by simple

```
$rowset = $this->tableGateway->select($where);
```

In my MySQL database I have procedure **GetObjectsInCityRange(city, range)** which returns all object_id in range of geocoded city coordinates

I intend to add in the where clause condition:

```
WHERE object_id IN (call GetObjectsInCityRange(city, range))
```

Is it possible with MySQL? How write correctly $where array element to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

You can call a `where()` method in your select object and call `in()` on the return value or create a where statement.

E.g.

```
$select = new Select();
$select->from($this->tableName)->columns(array($expression));
$where = new Where();
$where->in($identifier, $valueSet);
// or
$where->addPredicate(
    new Predicate\In($identifier, $valueSet)
);
// and then
$select->where($where);
```

and append it to the select object.

The link below is exactly what you need I believe :)
http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.1/en/modules/zend.db.sql.html#in-identifier-array-valueset-array

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

For MySQL it is suggested that you should use function instead of procedure as function can be used in any sql query while procedure is itself a query like statement.  Ex.

```
call MyPrcedure();

SET var = MyFunction();
```

So you can call function in your query most of the time. However as per my knowledge function will return valid mysql data-type like varchar, int float etc. So query rows may not be available in your In query. Then only way to execute your query to convert your procedure logic to a subquery and pass inside IN statement.

```
WHERE object_id IN (SUB_QUERY)
```

Comment: I figured out that it is too complicated to solve this in MySQL the way I would do it for example in Firebird where my SUB_QUERY would be simple `SELECT object_id from SP`.

Comment: I figured out that it is too complicated to solve this in MySQL the way I would do it for example in Firebird where my SUB_QUERY would be simple  `SELECT object_id from SP`  I solved it by generating table data with distances between each object_id and city. Next I join both tables and restrict result to required distance range.